# laravel 6.5 shows an edit url with a question mark

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel 6.5 when using the route helper function and creating an edit link the output that i get is myurl/myroute?id=1 where before it was myurl/myroute/1/edit. How can i go back to the previous state?

this is my code, my routes are named.

```
<a href="{{ route('project.edit', ['id' => $project->id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a route resource:

```
Route::resource('project', 'ProjectsController);
```

Then it uses `{project}` as the model binding so instead of `id` you should pass `project`.

```
{{ route('project.edit', $project) }}
```

Should work just fine and replace the wild card with the id of the model.

Running `php artisan route:list` will give you exactly the name of the parameter expected in the route :)

Comment: thanks that worked :) now i got to update the whole thing with that lol

Comment: @SarmenB. well good luck :) if you didn't used array as a second parameter it would've been easier, if you had just `$project->id` it will work the same as the one I showed above. But using associative array is what breaks it unfortunately.